# How to setup socket.io as service on Android

Tags: android, service, socket.io

I have a activity login, 3 fragments and 2 activity chat (1 for groupchat and 1 for single chat), so I want hold connect of socket.io when I change activity. Hope everyone help me.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you do not want to keep it IN THE BACKGROUND : meaning you only need connection around the application lifecycle and neverless needed whenever the application is killed,you can simply keep reference to socket IO throughout the Application itself.

The good example with github is here

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat